# Eigenvector of large sparse stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have a large sparse matrix corresponding to a system of master equations for a continuous-time Markov chain. It's approximately $500,000 \times 500,000$, with a density of around $10^{-6}$.

Is there a quick(er) way to calculate just the eigenvector corresponding to the $\lambda=0$ eigenvector, (I'm currently using eigs in matlab) particularly for when I need to do this for larger matrices?

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of [Cuthill-McKee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill–McKee_algorithm)?

Comment: Perhaps the inbuilt function [U,S,V]= [sdks](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svds.html) (A,k,'smallest') , which is better designed for sparse matrices could help. Haven't tested it.

Comment: if you have estimates on the modulus of the smallest non-zero eigenvalue, you can basically do 'inverse power iteration' (or rayleigh quotient iteration) i,e. consider the matrix $B=A+\delta I$ and consider randomly generated vector  and compute $B^{-k}\mathbf x$ where you don't actually invert B, but just repeatedly apply sparse solver. This should converge very quickly, because for a sufficiently small $\delta$ your zero eigenvalue becomes much bigger in modulus in $B^{-1}$ than everything else. You'd want to normalize your vector as you go along.